# How to get product tag name and all category and all product under to it using woocommerce Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new in Wordpress and I am very confused about it. It is possible to get data like for example I have two specials tags, Monthly special and expiry stock special.

Tag Name: `MONTHLY SPECIAL`

Category: AYUSH HERBS

Products: Amla Plex, Ayu-Dep, Regu-Cycle, Ayu-Test

Category: ATRANTIL

Products: Atrantil

Tag Name: `EXPIRY STOCK SPECIAL`

Category: AYUSH HERBS

Products: Amla Plex, Ayu-Dep, Regu-Cycle, Ayu-Test

Category: ATRANTIL

Products: Atrantil

So, I want to display data in page like below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8ltlkax77mhgmc/specials.png?dl=0

I want data like wise for both monthly specials and expiry stock specials.

Comment: Woocommerce "Product tags" are not linked in any way to "Product categories" …

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Is there another way? So, I can access data like wise?

Comment: Everything is possible in Woocommerce depending on your skills, knowledge and time to be spent. What you are asking is just complicated and too broad for StackOverFlow to be answered without any provided code. If I had the answer, I will answer.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I am not skilled and I am learning all the things at this point I am stuck so, I would ask to stack overflow because I didn't find out any way to solve this issue.